# AWS API Gateway with API keys - get usage insights

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have my public API running on AWS API Gateway, and now I want to add API keys to it, basically to see "who is using which endpoint and how many time per month/week/whatever". My API already has user management logic, with its own users db table.

The part I need help with is the analytics part - say I have this up and running, I need to be able to extract some sort of report saying, for each user (by name), how many calls were made to each endpoint. So far, the closest I've gotten was https://stackoverflow.com/a/52361117/1514576 which gets me the info I need by API key. The part that I'm missing is how I could potentially cross-reference this data with my "users" database table.

I was hoping one of you had faced a similar problem and could share how you handled it.